# My firestore database is in datastore mode, but I want native mode

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I go to the firestore console to try to change or delete the Datastore mode firestore (I want native mode) I get the message that "Database deletion is not available in the console during preview, please use the gcloud CLI to delete databases".

Questions:

1. What is preview, and how did that happen (it's a new project - is this just a delay of some kind)
2. I don't have gcloud, and I didn't need it for a different firebase project. Do I need it now?
3. How did the firestore Datastore mode get established?
4. How to I switch my firestore database to native mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found a location to query the Datastore database, and as the datastore was empty, I was offered the option to convert the database to Native mode, which I did.